# Having trouble translating this ES6 to ES5 including spread syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am trying to translate the following into ES5, while learning the language:

```
const transitionendFn = ()=> {
    [...this.slider].forEach((el)=> el.className = 'item');
    selectedEl.classList.add('active');
    this.isAnimating = false
}
```

ES5:

```
const transitionendFn = function() {
    [].concat(this.slider).
        forEach(function (el) {
            return el.className = 'item';
        });
    selectedEl.classList.add('active');
    this.isAnimating = false
}
```

I don’t understand the spread part.

`this.slider` contains the following:

[image]

Any help correcting this code is appreciated.

I get “`TypeError`: `el` is undefined” with my translation.

Comment: `[...this.slider].forEach` could be translated as `Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.slider, ...`. The `[...foo]` idiom is a way to convert an array-like object or iterable into an array.

Comment: `[...this.slider]` is loosely equal to `Array.from(this.slider)`. `this.slider` should be converted to array because it is iterable here (which may be or may not be an array).

Comment: ES5 doesn't have `const`.

Comment: @torazaburo Just iterables, not arbitrary array-likes. Only `Array.from` handles array-likes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that:

- Arrow functions do not have a `this` binding. Traditional functions (the only kind available in ES5) do, so you will have to bind it to the desired value.
- ES5 does not have `const` variables. Only `var` ones.
- ES5 does not have iterable objects. I will assume `this.slider` is array-like.

Then the translation would be something like

```
var transitionendFn = function() {
  [].forEach.call(this.slider, function(el) {
    return el.className = 'item';
  });
  selectedEl.classList.add('active');
  this.isAnimating = false;
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: Thank you @Oriol and all the persons who participated, I was reading all the suggestions, so much information to learn in so quick time. It worked.